# Angularjs - watch modal window close from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have main controller with

```
$scope.showDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: 'DialogController',
      templateUrl: 'partials/dialog.tmpl.ejs',
      targetEvent: ev
    })
};
```

and dialog contoller with

```
$scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
};
```

(The dialog directive I'm using is from angular material). 
How can I watch when dialog window is closed from main controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the promise returned from the `mdDialog`:

```
 $mdDialog.show({
      controller: 'DialogController',
      templateUrl: 'partials/dialog.tmpl.ejs',
      targetEvent: ev
 }).then(function(data) {
      // dialog was hidden with $mdDialog.hide()
 }, function() {
      // dialog was canceled with $mdDialog.cancel()
 })
```

Comment: I was also thinking about service saving some true/false variable listening to hide() function, but this solution is definitely better. Thanks.